# Showing that a sequence is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is: $a_{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{a_{n}}}$ and $a_{1}=2$

I've already shown that $2\leq a_{n}\leq 1+\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}$

Expressing $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ gave me: $\frac{-3(a_{n}-(1-\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}))(a_{n}-(1+\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}))}{3a_{n}+1}$  which is positive using the established bounds, hence the sequence is increasing.

Is this correct? Is there another way to prove that the sequence is increasing?

Comment: Consider the derivative of the auxiliary function $f(x) = 2 + \dfrac{1}{3 + \frac{1}{x}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct (and the solution as well).

Here is another approach. Put:

$$f(x) = 2 + \frac{x}{3x+1}$$

$f$ is increasing everywhere on its domain, and we have $a_2 > a_1$, hence $a_3 = f(a_2) > f(a_1) = a_2$, etc. we get that, by induction, $a_{n+1} > a_n$ for all $n$, i.e. that $(a_n)$ is increasing.

To find $\lim a_n$, you can solve the equation $f(x) = x$ to get:

$$x = 1 \pm \sqrt{\frac53}$$

Now note that $a_n \ge 2$, hence $\lim a_n \ge 2 > 1 - \sqrt{\frac53}$, so it must be that $\lim a_n = 1 + \sqrt{\frac53}$

Answer (score 1):

In terms of continued fractions,
$$ \alpha = [2;3,2,3,2,3,\ldots] = [2;3,\alpha] = \frac{3+\sqrt{15}}{3} \tag{1}$$
so
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\underbrace{[2;3,2,3,2,\ldots,3,2]}_{2n-1 \text{ numbers}}=\alpha =\color{red}{\frac{3+\sqrt{15}}{3}}.\tag{2}$$
The monotonicity follows from a general property of the continued fractions: if $\left\{\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right\}$ is the sequence of convergents, both $\left\{\frac{p_{2n}}{q_{2n}}\right\}$ and $\left\{\frac{p_{2n+1}}{q_{2n+1}}\right\}$ are monotonic sequences.